# TextField's text does not update after changing its controller's text in onChanged field

Tags: flutter

I have a textfield with a controller. What I want to do is change the input characters as they are being received. But what happens is that it replaces the first entered character, but then, the controller's text does not update on changes afterwards. Actually, nothing happens when you press a key.

here is my textfield:

```
TextEditingController amountController = TextEditingController();
TextField(
  controller: amountController,
  onChanged: (value) {
  amountController.text = replaceFarsiNumber(value);
  },
)
```

Here is the replaceFarsiNumber() function for further information:

```
String replaceFarsiNumber(String input) {
  const english = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
  const farsi = ['۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹'];
  for (int i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
    input = input.replaceAll(english[i], farsi[i]);
  }
  return input;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of struggle, I figured out that when we change the `amountController.text`, the cursor moves to the beginning of the text, and therefore, you can't edit the `textField`'s value nor it updates on changes. So, you had to reposition the cursor to the end of string manually:

```
    onChanged: (value) {
      controller1.text = replaceFarsiNumber(value);
      //reposition the cursor to the end of string
      controller1.selection =
          TextSelection.fromPosition(
              TextPosition(offset: value.length));
    },
```

Comment: The problem was that when you set the controller's text property, the whole thing is selected. Every keystroke is _replacing_ the text in the box. You adding the controller1.selection property is (as you correctly said) putting the cursor after the final character.

Answer (score 1):

your code seems correct, to double check I tried your code and it runs correctly. Here is the output:

[image]

There may be another reason of your problem...

Comment: Your answer seems false since I think you have entered numbers in order from 1 to 9; however, they are in reverse order in the picture. This happens if you not specify the `keyboardType`. If you specify the type as `keyboardType.number`, you will see it would not work. I figured out the problem and wrote the answer under the post. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that it enters an infinite loop. `onChanged` changes the text which in turn triggers a new `onChanged` and this goes on infinitely. It might help to only assign to the text when the text is different. So like

```
onChanged: (value) {
  var newValue = replaceFarsiNumber(value);
  if (value != newValue) {
    amountController.text = newValue;
  }
},
```

Comment: I did as you said but it didn't work.